# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'l' of

Tags: c#

Please help me with this code.I a beginner programmer and not know how to fix this problem.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace How_many_can
    {
        class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int m = n;
            var l = n.ToString();
            var k = l.Count();
            int sum = 0;
            int how_many_can = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(How_many_can(n, sum, how_many_can, m,l));
        }
        static int How_many_can(int n, int sum, int how_many_can, int m, int k,string l)
        {
            if (sum > n)
            {
                return how_many_can;
            };
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                sum += m % 10;
                m /= 10;
            };
            how_many_can += 1;
            n -= sum;
            l = n.ToString();
            k = l.Count();
            return How_many_can(n, sum, how_many_can, m, k,l);
        }
    }
}
```

[IMAGE WITH PROBLEM!!!!!!!!!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhQv1.png)

Comment: Where is the error?  What line?

Comment: Well, you missed to provide `k` at the first call to `How_many_can`.

Comment: try this => `Console.WriteLine(How_many_can(n, sum, how_many_can, m, k, l));`

Comment: You're not passing any value for k.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Sorry working i mistaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have failed to pass a parameter for `l` on the line:

`Console.WriteLine(How_many_can(n, sum, how_many_can, m,l));`

It should be:

`Console.WriteLine(How_many_can(n, sum, how_many_can, m,k,l));`

Comment: Thanks you helped me!

Answer (score 0):

The `How_many_can` method has 6 parameters, but you passed only 5 in `Main`.

I think you meant to write:

`Console.WriteLine(How_many_can(n, sum, how_many_can, m, k, l));`

Comment: Haunting for rep.?

Comment: Maybe i say wrong but i understand so you hated new ysurs or begining programers?(Begining programers it i)